# How to uplaod an image using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET C# with entity framework and I'm trying to upload image for a profile and display it.

Here is the relevant part of the View file (Manage.cshtml)

```
<input type="file" name="form-register-photo" id="form-register-photo" disabled>
```

Here is the relevant part of the Controller file (Manage.cs)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Manage(ManageViewModel manageviewmodel,HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    TheFoodyContext db = new TheFoodyContext();
    User user_to_update = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(s => s.email == manageviewmodel.Email);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (user_to_update != null && (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0))
        {

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/FOODY"), fileName);

            user_to_update.email = manageviewmodel.Email;
            user_to_update.fname = manageviewmodel.FirstName;
            user_to_update.lname = manageviewmodel.LastName;
            user_to_update.phone = manageviewmodel.Phone;
            user_to_update.photo = path;
            user_to_update.address = manageviewmodel.Address;
            user_to_update.city = manageviewmodel.City;
            user_to_update.postcode = manageviewmodel.PostCode;
            user_to_update.district = manageviewmodel.District;
            user_to_update.user_type = manageviewmodel.UserType;
            user_to_update.status = manageviewmodel.Status;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }

    }
    return View(manageviewmodel);

}
```

Within the above controller i have coded for other fields also. So I want to upload the picture among with them. That means from a single button click.

Here is my Model class (ManageViewModel.cs)

```
public class ManageViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Photo { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public int PostCode { get; set; }

    public string District { get; set; }

    public string UserType { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

But for this one photo uploading part did not work properly. So I really don't know how to manage this.

Comment: From your code it looks like you want to store the file on the server's file system and then store the path to that file in the database.  Is that correct?  Also, what does "did not work properly" mean?  What exactly didn't work, and what were any errors that you got?

Comment: Your file input has `name="form-register-photo"`, therefore the parameter in the POST method must match - `HttpPostedFileBase form-register-photo`

Comment: Not any errors but the path to that file does not goes to the database.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yeah. Thanks. But still i didn't solve my problem.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: It doesn't store the path to the relevant file in the database. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on `user_to_update.photo = path;` what's the value of `path`? Are there any exceptions being thrown? Are you checking the correct database for the data?

Comment: There is an code example here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/658522/Storing-Images-in-SQL-Server-using-EF-and-ASP-NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't help you to literally upload an image.

1. From your code, you only just edit 1 record in `Users` in database, without actually upload the image to hosting drive.

For simple, you will need to have something like below to store the file in physically:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/FOODY"), fileName);
upload.SaveAs(newSPath);
```

2. You didn't show exactly what is the result after this `db.SaveChanges();` show I'm not sure whether your photo path getting any error. My suggestion is add in a `try catch block` and run the code in Debug, see what will you have in `user_to_update.photo` after `db.SaveChanges();`